# How to hide the NGINX "server" response header (e.g nginx/1.12.2) in Amazon Linux 2 (AMI)?

Tags: nginx, amazon-linux

ASAIK, we need to install 3rd party modules (e.g more_clear_headers) and add configure in nginx.conf to remove the server header completely.

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

http {
    ...
    more_clear_headers Server;
    ...
}
```

However, in AMI, how to do that?

There is no package by using this command:
$ yum install more_clear_headers

Answer (score 0):

Remove at least the version number with

```
server_tokens off;
```

The `Server` response header will be

```
Server: nginx
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens

Answer (score -2):

There are only commercial solutions available to install from packages. You can either use NGINX Plus (expensive), or a cheaper GetPageSpeed repository that supports Amazon Linux 2.

Follow through [the article](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/how-to-remove-the-server-header-in-nginx) to set up the module from GetPageSpeed repo:

```
sudo yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-latest.rpm
sudo yum -y install nginx-module-headers-more
```

Now you can adjust your `nginx.conf` like this:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

http {
    ...
    more_clear_headers Server;
    ...
}
```